# Por qué los elementos de mi web se ven enormes?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

No sé nada de programación, quiero comenzar por ahí. Por eso, desde ya, agradezco toda ayuda.
Estoy creando este sitio web alojado en Hostinger.
https://bonosdecasinosonline.com/
Y hasta ahora todo bien con él.
Pero...
Tengo la intención de incluir una red social dentro de ese sitio web y para eso creé un subdominio en Hostinger.
Ya instalé el Tema Buddyx y el plugin gratuito BuddyPress
Sin embargo, la red social se ve extraña, con los elementos súper grandes y no sé cómo cambiar este problema de consiguración.
Aquí está.
https://cajeros.bonosdecasinosonline.com/

Quedo al tanto de las respuestas. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Tita, bienvenida, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, evitar recibir votos negativos, y acceder a una mejor respuesta, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Hola Tita, bienvenida, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, evitar recibir votos negativos, y acceder a una mejor respuesta, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.